# Pass the layout param for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there a way to tell devise to use a specific design, not the layout/application.html.erb ?

I thought I could create a controller class like:

```
class DeviseController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'devise'
end
```

with a routes like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "devise" }
```

but this doesnt work, it gives me a 404.

Shouldn't the extends responds to the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 more minutes I found the answer myself...

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/b83b1dbd864cdb93/9b146e3b64e8c83a

Just add the layout as sessions.html.erb